# iif statement in Reporting Services only including values in a group

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

In Reporting Services 2005 I have created a table that has a few groups in it. I would like to perform a rudimentary `iif()` on one of the columns in the group and though the Intellisense says I am formatting my `iif()` correctly, when I go to preview the report I am told I am missing my false part. In addition, the ',' after Value is underlined as a syntax error.

```
=Sum(iif((Fields!Repeat.Value, "Departments") = "*", 0, Fields!Hours_Earned.Value))
```

The group I am working with is called "Departments" and there is a nvarchar column that occasionally has a asterisk sign in it.  If there is an asterisk anywhere in that column for this group, I want a 0 to be displayed, etc.  Any ideas? It seems as though the first ',' is being misconstrued to be the ending of my expression in the `iif()`, but it is not, and it is inside parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only want to place the name of the group at the very end of the aggregation function. Switching to this format solved my problem:

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!Repeat.Value = "*", 0, Fields!Hours_Earned.Value), "Departments")
```